# http запросы к API исполняются больше 20 секунд

Tags: django, api, http

У меня есть приложение на django, которое может искать видео на YouTube через YouTube Data API v3 и переводить их описание с помощью Yandex Translate API. Зачастую все работает прекрасно, оба сервиса нормально отвечают. Но примерно раз в 10 вызовов, запрос растягивается секунд на 20. И с переводом и с ютубом такое.

В консоли разработчика смотрю, в графе "Ожидание (Время получения первого байта)" как раз эти 20 секунд и есть. Не понимаю, почему так, вряд ли проблема на стороне сервисов, она ведь на обоих наблюдается. Но никак не могу понять, в чем у меня тогда проблема...

Я пробовал DEBUG поставить на False, где-то советовали. Но проблема не ушла.

Не знаю, насколько это важно, но приложение на локалхосте на 5000 порту стоит.

Код функций получения данных с YouTube:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import os
import pickle

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]


def auth():
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    credentials_filename = "credentials.json"
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
        credentials = pickle.load(token)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials_filename, SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=8000)
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)
    return build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

def search(youtube, **kwargs):
    return youtube.search().list(part="snippet", **kwargs).execute()
```

Код их вызова:

```
yt = auth()
response = search(yt, q=request.POST['search'], maxResults=20, type='video')['items']
```

Код функции для Yandex API:

```
endpoint_url = 'https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate'
list_texts = [str(texts[key]) for key in texts]
body = {
    "targetLanguageCode": language,
    "texts": list_texts,
    "folderId": self.folder_id,
}
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {0}".format(self.token)
}
response = requests.post(endpoint_url, json=body, headers=headers)
```

UPD: Это проблема конкретно моего компьютера. Где она кроется, выяснить пока не смог. На всех остальных компьютерах все хорошо. Если вам известно, в чем проблема, буду рад, если поделитесь ответом

Comment: Ну бывает. Может интернет в этот момент просел у провайдера или слишком тяжёлый запрос или сервер Ютуба был слишком занят.

Comment: Мне кажется проблема в другом чем то... Как я выяснил, запросы идут не примерно 20 секунд, а 21 секунду ровно. При чем не настолько редко, что можно на просадку инета скинуть. У меня приложение на локалхосте на 5000 порту, это может влиять как то? Просто я за сетевые протоколы и всю эту тему не сильно разбираюсь

Comment: Попробуйте провести эксперимент: отправлять запросы очень редко. Если задержка не повтоится - значит, Вас ограничивает rate limiter сервиса. И еще один признак - это одновременно оба сервиса тормозят, или "по одному"

Comment: Видимо пробелма не в этом. Я с Postman в ручную попробовал отправлять запросы, очень активно клацал, примерно раза 2-3 в секунду. Конкретно к переводчику. Все там было хорошо, за две минуты ни одного сбоя, а это куча запросов. Если же программно эти запросы например через for слать с моего приложения, то это ограничение выходит часто, примерно каждый 5 раз. Не понимаю уже ничего...

Comment: Есть подозрение, что в коде где-то не хватает блок `with`, из-за чего утекают открытые соединения.